# Set<sobject> doesn't maintain uniqueness although I am fetching Id field

Tags: apex, soql, list, set

I am trying to upsert a list of records and I may get duplicates so what I did In loop I am adding records to a set then that set into the list for DML.

Now problem is coming when I add a record in set then also I am getting duplicates although I have included this record id while querying.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

here is an example, why storing in `Set` sobjects is a not a best idea.

```
Id someAcctId = '001Z000001ORdLz';
Account acct1 = [
    select Id, Name
    from Account
    where Id = :someAcctId
    ];
Account acct2 = [
    select Id, Name
    from Account
    where Id = :someAcctId
    ];
acct2.Name += 'Z';

Set<Account> accts = new Set<Account>();
accts.add(acct1);
accts.add(acct2);

System.debug('accts.size():' + accts.size()); // accts.size():2 oops, size is 2
System.debug('accts:' + accts); // two account records are printed
```

So uniquness of records is defined **NOT ONLY by Id**, but rest of the fields are considered as well.

---

in order to correct storing records to update, you can use `Map<Id, Sobject>`

```
Id someAcctId = '001Z000001ORdLz';
Account acct1 = [
    select Id, Name
    from Account
    where Id = :someAcctId
    ];
Account acct2 = [
    select Id, Name
    from Account
    where Id = :someAcctId
    ];
acct2.Name += 'Z';

Map<Id, Sobject> sobjectsToUpdate  = new Map<Id, Sobject>();
sobjectsToUpdate.put(acct1.Id, acct1);
sobjectsToUpdate.put(acct2.Id, acct2);

System.debug('sobjectsToUpdate.size():' + sobjectsToUpdate.size()); // sobjectsToUpdate.size():1 nice!
System.debug('sobjectsToUpdate:' + sobjectsToUpdate); // one account record is printed
```

Try to put in sets (or in keys of map) immutable types

---

in your current case, if you want to call `upsert` DML, you can have two collections: `Map` to store records to update with key by `Id` and `List` for records to insert. Merge them into one collection and do `upsert`.

```
Map<Id, Sobject> sobjectsToUpdate  = new Map<Id, Sobject>();
List<Sobject> sobjectsToInsert = new List<Sobject>();

...

List<Sobject> sobjectsToUpsert = new List<Sobject>();
sobjectsToUpsert.addAll(sobjectsToUpdate);
sobjectsToUpsert.addAll(sobjectsToInsert);

upsert sobjectsToUpsert;
```

Comment: This also applies to Lists -- which is good to keep in mind if you need to see whether records have been modified by some other process:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51204/best-way-to-find-which-records-have-been-modified-in-a-list/235054#235054